# Use Cmake with Yocto

Tags: cmake, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I’m trying to write a recipe for a soft that compiles using cmake, let’s call it my-software.bb

I know I got to inherit the cmake and pkgconfig classes

However I am wondering about the PACKAGE variable. Do I need to explicitly define each package (and the FILES variables associated) ? Or I can just add :

IMAGE_INSTALL += “my-software” and the cmake class will do the package splitting work ?

I don’t know if my question is clear, but any help would be appreciated :-)

William

Answer (score 1):

The default packaging rules are generally sufficient so yes just inherit cmake.

Comment: Alright, I’ll try it ! :-) thanks. And btw, how do I know what I have to put in the DEPENDS or RDEPENDS variables ? I just refer to the CMakeLists files ?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to read the cmakelists to see what the dependencies are.